# How to pass data from model to controller (CodeIgniter, session help)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

First sorry for my english( it is not my main language ).

I am new in CodeIgniter3 and i like it.

Lets say this is my model:

```
function login($uname, $upassword)
    {
        $this->db->where('uname', $uname);
        $this->db->where('upassword', $upassword);
        $query = $this->db->get('zamestnanci');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data['zamestnanec'] = $row->tpred_zamestnanci." ".$row->meno_zamestnanci. " ".$row->priezvisko_zamestnanci." ".$row->tza_zamestnanci;;
        }
        return ($data);

    }
```

And this is my controller:

```
//Funkcia na prihlásenie používatela
    function loginUser()
    {
        //Načítať model
        $this->load->model('user_model');

        $uname              = $this->input->post('uname');
        $upassword          = $this->input->post('upassword');
        $meno               = $this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword);

        //Ak sa meno a heslo zhoduje
        if ($this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword)) 
        {

            $this->session->set_userdata('user', $meno);
            $data['user']   = $this->session->userdata('user');
            redirect('/otk/', $data);
        } 
        else 
        {
            redirect('/user/');
        }
    }
```

I want to ask you how to pass/display data from model to session. To `$this->session->userdata('user')`.

Can you explain me the correct process off passing data from model to controller and from model to session. (like if you were trying to explain to a man who is thinking slowly).

I do not want links to documentation, just one or few persons who can explain it on example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the model to controller whether data is correct or not. no need a big loop there in the model

**In Model**

```
function login($uname, $upassword)
{
    $this->db->where('uname', $uname);
    $this->db->where('upassword', $upassword);
    $query = $this->db->get('zamestnanci');

    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result); # get how many data passed

    if ($count == 1) {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
function loginUser()

    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $uname              = $this->input->post('uname');
    $upassword          = $this->input->post('upassword');
    //$meno               = $this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword);

    //Ak sa meno a heslo zhoduje
    $validate = $this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword);
    if ($validate != false) 
    {
        # Valid user
        # $validate conating user details too. to check add this next line print_r($validate);die;
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $uname);
        redirect('/otk/');
    } 
    else 
    {
        # Invalid User
        redirect('/user/');
    }
}
```

[And in `otk` function just call session value `user`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?#retrieving-session-data)

Comment: I have another question if it is possible to pass all data from function login() to display currently logged user. I mean display his name, surname, etc. Because when i do this: $this->session->userdata('user') it will display: Logged as (my login username) and i want to display full name + surname from table.

Comment: yes you can. add this `echo $validate[0]['name_field'];die;` inside if condition

Comment: Okay but now when i try `$this->session->set_userdata('user', $validate);` and in my view('base_view); i do `$this->session->userdata('user');` it will display error array to string. But when i want know all user data in session `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` it will display right data.

Comment: @Nezo no assign them manually,  `$this->session->set_userdata('userName', $validate[0]['name'])`  and `$this->session->set_userdata('birthday', $validate[0]['bday_field'])`  .. likewise

Comment: Okay thank you this work perfect but is it possible to add this `$this->session->set_userdata('userName', $validate[0]['name'])` `$this->session->set_userdata('birthday', $validate[0]['bday_field'])` to for example array $user and than in view do `$this->session->userdata($user);`

Comment: If you set `set_userdata('userName'` ike this then access it `userdata('userName')`

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass information from model to controller in two ways.

- By using session
- first fetch information using query and return that array to controller.

> it is good if you return data to controller first then in controller
>   set up the session by using that returned array.

As in this example.

**Model**

```
function login($uname, $upassword)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $tthis->db->from("table_name")
    $this->db->where('uname', $uname);
    $this->db->where('upassword', $upassword);
    $query = $this->db->get('zamestnanci');
     // you can user result_array() to get all information in array form.
    $this->result = $query->result_array();
    return $this->result;

}
```

**In Controller**

```
//Funkcia na prihlásenie používatela
function loginUser()
{
    //Načítať model
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $uname              = $this->input->post('uname');
    $upassword          = $this->input->post('upassword');
    $meno               = $this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword);

    //Ak sa meno a heslo zhoduje
    if ($this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword)) 
    {

        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $meno); // here you are setting up the session.
        $data['user']   = $this->session->userdata('user');
        redirect('/otk/', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        redirect('/user/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

get all the user information (in array) from the model whatever you want  :

In controller :

**First way :**

```
$uname              = $this->input->post('uname');
$upassword          = $this->input->post('upassword');
$lname              = $this->input->post('lname');//example

$session_arr['uname'] = $uname;
$session_arr['fullname'] = $fname.' '.$lname; // example
$this->session->set_userdata($session_arr);
```

**Second way :**

```
$user = $this->user_model->login($uname, $upassword);
if ($user != false) 
{
    // Valid user
    // $validate containing user details too. to check add this next line
    // print_r($validate);die;
    $this->session->set_userdata($user);
    redirect('/otk/');
}
```

for more : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session

```
$user = array(
    'username'  => 'johndoe',
    'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($user);
```